# Shell command to find the longest consecutive simple repeat of a pattern/word occurring on a single line of the text file

Tags: shell, unix, grep

What is the longest consecutive simple repeat of the pattern (eg: "ABC") occurring on a single line in the text file?

I believe I need to use regular expression (regex) matches with grep. But am unable to figure the right statement.

$ grep '["pattern"]+' file.txt

The longest consecutive simple repeat on a single line of the specified pattern must be returned

Comment: it would help if you added a few sample input lines and showed the exact output lines needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only a matched text.

```
$ cat file.txt 
ABC
OTHER ABCABCABC OTHER
ABCABC
$ grep -f <(grep -oE "(ABC)+" file.txt | sort | tail -1) file.txt
OTHER ABCABCABC OTHER
```

Comment: How could I get the longest match from all the lines of the file?

Comment: Fixed. Do you need the whole line?

Comment: Yes, I need the whole line

Comment: the whole line.

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` version:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {n=split($i,a,"ABC")-1;if(n>x) {c=$0;x=n}}} END {if (c) print c}' file
OTHER ABCABCABC OTHER
```

It test each field and with spilt, see how many `ABC` there are. If its more than other line, store the line and print it at final.